# TFS 2010: How to check in files that were deleted but not deleted through TFS

Tags: tfs

I have some files in a local workspace that were checked out and then deleted but were not deleted through TFS. TFS still has them marked as "edit" in the pending changes view. When I try to check-in the deleted files, I get an error saying the files cannot be found. Is there a way to tell TFS that these files have been deleted and that they should be deleted in source control as well?

Answer (score 4):

You could, through `team explorer`, right click on the deleted files and do a `undo pending changes`.  Then through `team explorer` delete them and check them in.

If that doesn't work - right click on the deleted file through `team explorer`; do a `get specific version` and check both checkboxes to overwrite files:

[image]

This will fetch the deleted [from workspace] file from TFS.  Perform an `undo pending changes` on the file.  Then delete the file through team explorer and check it in.

Comment: This is basically the route I went with. I took a screenshot of the pending changes view, undid changes, then re-deleted the files using explorer. I wish TFS did a better job of handling missing files, such as giving an option to delete them instead of just throwing an error message on check-in.

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't too many files, just create some dummy ones on disk, check them in, then delete them through TFS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do this via source control explorer: View -> Other Windows -> Source Control Exlorer.  Find the code file that you want to mark as deleted and right-click and select delete.

For future reference, [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f) is very useful for this kind of thing.